# Position several elements in button

Tags: html, css

I am currently working on a forum project, and had some problems with the `CSS` styling.
I am trying to position text into a `HTML button`, I managed to position one part of the text correctly, but the other part can't be positioned as the first, even if the `CSS` and `HTML` code is the same.
I tried wrapping the elements in a div, and somehow, I never manage to get them displayed into the button, even with margin-bottom.

[image: Image of the page]

Here the HTML Code:

```
 <button>
                    <div class="forum-list-header">
                        <div class="forum-list-border"><i class="fa-solid fa-laptop-code fa-2xl"></i></div>
                        <h2>Tech, Informatique et autres</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="forum-list-info">
                        <h3>5.1k</h3><h3>50.3k</h3>
                        <p>Posts</p><p>Messages</p>
                    </div>
                </button>
```

Here is the `CSS` code:

```
.forum-container {  /* This is wrapped around the button elements  */
    position:absolute;
    left:18%;
    margin-top:42em;
    font-family: Poppins-SemiBold, FontAwesome;
}

.forum-list-container { /* This is wrapped around the button elements */
    margin-top:3em;
}

.forum-list button { 
    background-color: #172129;
    border: 2px solid #212e38;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 10px 40px;
    width:80em;
    height: 10em;
    font-family: Poppins-SemiBold, FontAwesome;
    color:white;
    margin-right: 1em;
    display:block;
    margin-bottom: 2em;
}

.forum-list-header { /* Text aligned left, perfectly placed, won't work with the other text */
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
}

.forum-list h2 {
    margin-left:2em;
}

.forum-list .forum-list.btn {
    margin-bottom:2em;
}

.forum-list-info {
   /* Here should be the code to position it. */
}
```

Comment: It is hard trying to lay everything out depending on its width. Your layout looks like a table or grid. You might consider making the whole button into a grid with items the icon, the text and then an item containing the posts/messages info and laying that out as its own grid too. That way if the main texts are different lengths they will still align.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix for this:

I edited my `CSS` classes to:

```
.forum-list-info {
    grid-column-start: 2;
    grid-column-end: 3;
    margin-left: 17em;
}

.forum-list-info-numbers {
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    
}

.forum-list-info-text {
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;

}

.forum-list-info-numbers h3 {
    margin-right:6.3em;
    font-size:1.2em;
    
}

.forum-list-info-text p {
    margin-right:5em;
    font-size:1.2em;
    color:#a6afb6;

}
```

And my HTML:

```
  <button>
                    <div class="forum-list-header">
                        <div class="forum-list-border"><i class="fa-solid fa-rocket fa-2xl"></i></div>
                        <h2>Account Boost</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="forum-list-info">
                        <div class="forum-list-info-numbers"><h3>5.1k</h3><h3>50.3k</h3></div>
                        <div class="forum-list-info-text"><p>Posts</p><p>Messages</p></div>
                    </div>
                </button>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    .forum-list-info {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
}


//add this style to your css


<button>
    <div class="forum-list-header">
        <div class="forum-list-border"><i class="fa-solid fa-laptop-code fa-2xl"></i></div>
        <h2>Tech, Informatique et autres</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="forum-list-info">
        <div>
            <h3>5.1k</h3>
            <p>Posts</p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h3>50.3k</h3>
            <p>Messages</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</button>

//and replace this html code. you can get what you want.
```

Answer (score 0):

Should make each of those its own div, then style that div.

```
<button>
                    <div class="forum-list-header">
                        <div class="forum-list-border"><i class="fa-solid fa-laptop-code fa-2xl"></i></div>
                        <h2>Tech, Informatique et autres</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="forum-list-info">
                        <div><h3>5.1k</h3><p>Posts</p></div>
                        <div><h3>50.3k</h3><p>Messages</p></div>
                    </div>
                </button>
```

Comment: I tryied that out, but somehow to elements won't go up